# Is there a way to associate Automated tests to Test Cases in Azure DevOps using VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I've been looking for an extension for VS Code that will allow the "Associate Test Case" functionality provided with Visual Studio IDE and I have had no luck.
Is there an extension that provides this functionality?

Visual Studio steps:

1. Open Test Explorer
2. Right click on a Test Case
3. Click on Associate To Test Case

Screenshot:

[image: VS Associate To Test Case]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, currently there is no such extension provided in the visual studio code to support the "Associate Test Case" function.

You could add your request for this feature on [vscode UserVoice](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=feature_request.md) site  The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I created added a request for this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Check this extension that **I have created** https://github.com/JanuszNowak/janono.ado.testcase.associate.cli
it **allows associating in automatic manner**.
For now this is CLI, that you can run as vs-code task. Later I will create also dedicated Azure DevOps task. Visual Studio is not needed to run automatic association.
Code sample:

```
namespace ExampleTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    [janono.ado.testcase.associate.Organization("janono-pub")]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [janono.ado.testcase.associate.TestCase(5)] //<---
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            //yours test method content
            //...
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this work with Java ? Anything that can be there for Intellij ?

Comment: @GauravKhurana if you follow link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops check section Q: What types of tests are supported? I do not see java test case association even manual to be supported by Azure DevOps it self.